# How to get current frame?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I would like to send to another app current frame (number). Is it possible to access it in axWindowsMediaPlayer control?

Comment: Is all the code yours or third party tools (source code less) involved?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't see anything about this on axWindowsMediaPlayer control.

But you can use [FrameGrabber project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/FrameGrabber.aspx) to extract frames from a movie.
FrameGrabber is an open-source library written in c# and it is easy to use.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This may be an old thread, but I feel like the question did not properly get answered. This may not be the "frame number" but it does give you a "position" of the video that you could pass. I am using it to sync two videos.
This is for a media player that has already been added to a VB form called AxWindowsMediaPlayer1. I am sure something similar can be called in C#

```
Dim position As Double 
position = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition
```